# Did Windows 8 support Xamarin cross-platform development?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to know whether I can do cross-platform development in Windows 8 with Xamarin, or whether Windows 10 is required for it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at their documentation? It covers this.

Comment: I had searched for it but its not clear to me weather i can use windows 8 for cross-platform development or not

Comment: or can you share a link where i can get any information about it. That will be help full for me.

Answer (score -1):

[Windows System Requirements](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#windows)

> The minimum operating system version is Windows 7. Xamarin.Forms
>   Windows support requires Windows 8.1, and Xamarin.Forms UWP support
>   requires Windows 10

So, you can develop a Xamarin.Forms app on 8.1, but if you need to test for Universal Windows Platform, then you'll have to use Windows 10. You should do more research to see if that is important for you.